# How to get unique calendar event id for Android 4.0?

Tags: android-calendar

We are developing an application which will run on the all version of Android OS.

In our app we need to fetch the calendar events and those events will be added from the default calendar app which is coming with the mobile phone.

I have already checked CalendarContract.Calendars, CalendarContract.Events and CalendarContract.Attendees tables. In the Calendars table there is no event id . But in Events and Attendees tables event_id is there. If we insert a calendar event in the default calendar app in the Galaxy Nexus then it is inserting event_id as 1, 2 ,3 ,4. But in the Android 2.1 we are getting an excellent field called iCalGuid ... where we are getting the unique calendar eventId like GUID field ... Is their any way to get the Calendar event Id in Android 4.0 as iCalGuid in the lower version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a unique id by combining 5 columns of the calendar Event table -----

First set the calendar URI value as follows ---

```
Uri calenderContentUri;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8)
{
     calenderContentUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
}
else
{
    calenderContentUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
}
```

**NOTE :: Do not use the constant values like Events.CONTENT_URI . Instead of that, set the uri as shown above.**

**Next** I have made a custom composite unique **key** by combining 5 columns(title, ownerAccount, eventLocation, dtstart, dtend ) of Event table. This id I am using everywhere and it solved my problem.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                    {
                        String[] projection = null;
                        //By default  you have the following calendars in your android phone like 
                        //My Calendar, Gmail calendar,  Indian holydays or if you have installed some
                        //third party calendar app etc. They will be automatically given an unique id by OS.
                        //In the next line "selectedCalenderId" is indicating a perticular calendar like My Calendar or Gmail calendar.
                        //You need to write seperate code to get those particular calendar ids. here "selectedCalenderId" is that type of id(in my case value may be 0(My Calendar). 1(Gmail Calendar), or 3(Indian Holydays))
                        String selection = "calendar_id=" +selectedCalenderId +" and dtstart between ? and ?";

                        //provide the time range(in system mili seconds)  from what you want to get the events.
                        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {getTimeInMilisecond(day + " 00:00:00"), getTimeInMilisecond(day + " 23:59:59")};

                        Cursor cursor = null;

                        try
                        {
                            cursor = getContentResolver().query(calenderContentUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, "dtstart DESC, dtend DESC");
                            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                            {
                                int increment = 0;

                                String eventName;
                                String calendarOwnerName;
                                String location;
                                long eventBeginTime;
                                long eventEndTime;

                                String description;
                                String calendarSyncId;

                                String customCalendarEventId ;

                                do
                                {
                                    eventName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
                                    eventBeginTime = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("dtstart"));
                                    eventEndTime = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("dtend"));
                                    location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("eventLocation"));
                                    calendarOwnerName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ownerAccount"));
                                    description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description"));

                                    //Watch that I am combining the 4 columns
                                    calendarSyncId = eventName +"-" +calendarOwnerName +"-" +location +"-" +eventBeginTime+"-" +eventEndTime;

                                    //Making MD5 encryption to use it as unique key
                                    customCalendarEventId =  yourMD5EncryptionLogic(calendarSyncId);

                                    //TODO ::: Do the rest of your coding for OS version higher than 14.
                                }
                                while(cursor.moveToNext());
                            }
                        }
                        finally  {
                            if(cursor != null) {
                                cursor.close();
                            }
                        }
              }
              else
              {
                    String[] projection = null;
                    //By default  you have the following calendars in your android phone like 
                        //My Calendar, Gmail calendar,  Indian holydays or if you have installed some
                        //third party calendar app etc. They will be automatically given an unique id by OS.
                        //In the next line "selectedCalenderId" is indicating a perticular calendar like My Calendar or Gmail calendar.
                        //You need to write seperate code to get those particular calendar ids. here "selectedCalenderId" is that type of id(in my case value may be 0(My Calendar). 1(Gmail Calendar), or 3(Indian Holydays))
                    String selection = "calendar_id=" +selectedCalenderId +" and dtstart between ? and ?";
                    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {getTimeInMilisecond(day + " 00:00:00"), getTimeInMilisecond(day + " 23:59:59")};

                    Cursor cursor = null;

                    try
                    {
                        cursor = getContentResolver().query(calenderContentUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, "dtstart DESC, dtend DESC");
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                        {
                            int increment = 0;

                            String eventName;
                            String calendarOwnerName;
                            String location;

                            long eventBeginTime;
                            long eventEndTime;

                            String description;
                            String calendarGuid;

                            String customCalendarEventId;

                            int selfAttendanceStatusVal = -1;

                            do
                            {
                                selfAttendanceStatusVal = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("selfAttendeeStatus"));
                                eventName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
                                eventBeginTime = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("dtstart"));
                                eventEndTime = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("dtend"));
                                location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("eventLocation"));
                                calendarOwnerName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ownerAccount"));
                                description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description"));

                                //Watch that I am combining the 4 columns
                                calendarGuid = eventName +"-" +calendarOwnerName +"-" +location +"-" +eventBeginTime+"-" +eventEndTime;

                                //Making MD5 encryption to use it as unique key
                                customCalendarEventId =  yourMD5EncryptionLogic(calendarSyncId);

                                //TODO ::: Do the rest of your coding for OS version less than 14.
                            }
                            while(cursor.moveToNext());
                            }
                        }
                        finally  {
                            if(cursor != null) {
                                cursor.close();
                            }
                        }
              }
```

Comment: this is not possible anyway non practical